# JsonRest and EnhancedGrid plugins not playing nicely within dojo

Tags: rest, sorting, dojo, pagination

I have an enhanced grid that is populated via a ObjectStore which in turn is populated by a call to a rest service via a JsonRest object.

Data is being placed into the grid just fine however i have noted two odd behaviours.

1. Going through different pages of the paginated grid shows me the same results as are on page 1
2. Sorting does not work at all (i am using nested sorting)

my grid and stores are as follows:

```
 var myStore = new JsonRest (
 {
 target: "location/of/rest/service/with/params,
 idProperty : "id"
 });

 var objStore = new ObjectStore ({ objectStore: myStore });

 var layout = [[{layout stuff}];

 grid = new EnhancedGrid({
 id: 'griddles',
 store: objectStore,
 structure: layout,
 ......
 plugins: {
 indirectSelection: true,
 pagination : {
  pageSizes : [my page sizes],
  description : true,
  sizeSwitch : true,
  pageStepper : true,
  gotoButton : true,
  defaultPageSize : 5,
  maxPageStep : 10,
  position: "bottom"
 },
 exporter: true
 }},
 "grid");
 });
```

Any help would be appreciated; when i populated with static data using itemfilewriter it works fine both with pagination and sorting.

Answer (score 0):

`dojo/store/JsonRest` sends a request to the server for each ranged query, so it naturally relies on the server for paging, sorting, and filtering.  It is the server's responsibility for interpreting `JsonRest`'s requests and responding accordingly, and it sounds like yours isn't.

`JsonRest` indicates the range it is requesting via the `Range` header.  For example, a query starting at the beginning (index 0) and requesting 10 items would translate to `Range: items=0-9`, while requesting 10 items starting at index 10 would translate to `Range: items=10-19`.

Sort arguments are included in the query string, in the format `sort(+fieldname)` for ascending, or `sort(-fieldname` for descending.  If multiple sort fields are to be specified, they are expected to be comma delimited (e.g. `sort(+field1,-field2)`.  If you need this in a key-value pair, you can specify `sortParam` in the arguments object passed to `JsonRest`, in which case the query string will include something like `yourSortParam=sort(...)`.  You can also customize the `+` and `-` prefixes via `ascendingPrefix` and `descendingPrefix`.

These server expectations are documented in the [Reference Guide](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/quickstart/rest.html#restful-conventions-the-dojo-way).